# Передача ключа для подписи приложения

Tags: цифровая-подпись, авторские-права, юридические-аспекты

Киевский программист Владислав, на работе, сделал Android приложение, никаких бумаг не подписывал, ТЗ было поставлено в устной форме.

Подписал приложение своим ключом (с настоящими именем и фамилией).
Опубликовал приложение в Google Play, предварительно отправив сканы своих документов.

Через некоторое время, Владислав увольняется, передав весь код, и все доступы следующему программисту Тихону.

Но как быть с ключом для подписи приложения?
Передавать ключ кому-то не хочется. 
Теоретически следующий программист (Тихон) может добавить зловред в приложение, и подписать его ключом Владислава. И тогда, ниточка будет вести к Владиславу, к тому же есть сканы документов. Как минимум Владислава забанят в Google Play.

На само приложение этот ключ не влияют. Приложение можно подписать другим ключом. НО без ключа Владислава, не получится выпускать обновления для приложения. Так как обновления должны быть подписаны тем же ключом, который использовался изначально.

Как быть? Могут ли Владислава заставить отдать цифровой ключ в судебном порядке?

P.S. Все имена вымышленны, как в прочем и вся ситуация.

Comment: *"Могут ли Владислава заставить отдать цифровой ключ?"* это только Владиславу и отбирателям известно. Лучше акцентируйте вопрос на том как быть и как обычно такие ситуации решаются

Comment: Конечно же подразумевается цивилизованный способ. Можно ли обязать передать ключ в судебном порядке?

Comment: Старое приложение удалить, новое выпустить с тем же названием и с ключом уже организации а не автора.